# What is the hole in Obito's chest?

Tags: naruto

In Chapter 629, when Obito and Kakashi fought in Kamui's dimension, Obito revealed a hole in his chest and told Kakashi that the hole was opened by the hell of this world. It didn't seem to be a *literal* hole in his chest (like the Hollows in *Bleach*), because it wasn't present in the later part of the battle.

[image: Obito's hole]

Was this hole used figuratively to indicate that Obito's heart was void of emotions, or did he teleport that part of his chest just before Kakashi stabbed him with Raikiri?

Comment: Good question! And it seems to be something like the former, as Obito teleports to the other dimension when trying to avoid attacks. In this case, they are already in the alternate dimension, so it should be something figurative to the fact, Obito has no emotions and is too much consumed by what Madara had shown him of the world, long back.

Comment: This requires a good analysis to decipher. This is a good question but the answer, if not explained well, can be merely speculations.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Yeah, I think if one reads the chapters carefully, the answer can be found there. Right now, I don't feel like doing it, so asked the question here. ;) But if the answer is not clearly available, then multiple explanations supported by good evidence are also acceptable.

Comment: he teleported it.

Comment: It seems there are blood dripping in his chest hole, so it's safe to assume that he didn't transfer it out to the real world (we all know that he's phased his body countless time before without any injury received), also his shirt looks like it's been torned from a real physical attack. My guess is that he somehow make Kakashi sees Obito like that, just like later in that same chapter Kakashi sees the younger Obito and Rin. It must be because this is the Kamui's dimension, which belongs to Obito.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was never any real hole in Obito's chest. It was a genjutsu, as shown in Chapter 636.

The genjutsu was activated right from the moment Obito pierced himself into Kakashi's Raikiri. Kakashi realises the genjutsu after a while, asks Obito to drop the act and fight for real.

Comment: This is the right answer. :) Can you please expand on it? 
I thought I will wait for a week for someone else to answer, and then answer it myself if no one answers it.

Comment: @Happy : I have added some content with edit hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a genjutsu but after the "real fight", he got a real wound on his chest(a deliberate attempt by Obito to undo Madara's Seal and become the Ten Tails Jinchuuriki)